A place to solve a specific problem or a knowledge repository?
The rule accross the SE network is General Questions General Answers.
As shown by an answer in Meta.SE https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/402975/563808

They treat the site as a help desk, and don't realise that we're
trying to create a repository of knowledge in Q&A form.

The sites are a repository of knowledge.
But Parenting.SE seems to diverge asking for us to Focus on questions about an actual problem we have faced.
How does that work, does Parenting.SE deviate from the general philosophy in the SE network, did it become a place to solve a specifc problem?

Closing - the very premise of the question is incorrect, and honestly I'm beginning to feel like this is not a site for you. Everyone else reads the guidance and understands it and follows it, and yet you keep on trying to find ways to use the site in ways the community does not want it to be used.

@RoryAlsop An incorrect premise wouldn't mean the question is off-topic. If anything an incorrect premise makes the question exactly on topic. Someone should explain in the answer the misconception (what is actually true). What holds true for Parenting.SE. But I have the Parenting.SE tour on one hand and on the other many answers telling me SE is a repository of knowledge.

Of course SE is a repository of knowledge, but seriously, go back  and re-read our site tour and then one like SO or SE, and you'll see that you have it completely the wrong way round.

Parenting.SE follows the general philosophy just like the others, however it is more subjective, and less objective than the very tech sites.

Honestly, you have exhausted our patience with your continued attempts to actively misconstrue the rules, or to pick at areas where definition is woolly. If this site does not work for the way you want to use it, you should seriously consider using a different site.

@RoryAlsop I don't even undestand how it works so that I can say if it works the way I want to use it or not.

We keep telling you it doesn't work the way you seem to be trying to use it. That's why we keep saying stop.

@RoryAlsop Please tell me how it works then.

There‘s an old joke that goes as follows: A man goes to his doctor and explains: “When I poke my thigh, it hurts. When I poke my tummy, it hurts. Even when I poke my forehead, it hurts. What kind of mysterious ailment is this?” The doctor replies dryly: “You have a broken finger.”
So if you seek something (guidance?) on multiple sites and get replies from many people and it’s all equally uncomfortable, maybe there’s nothing wrong with the multitude being poked, maybe the issue is with the one doing the poking.

@Stephie The amount of META questions tagged Scope, Policy etc. indicates that I am not the broken finger. The replies are not uncomfortable but unintelligible.

Ah. So you can understand non-literal replies? Thanks for proving that. And the amount of questions is no indication of a problem (in fact, it’s the reason meta exists), because questions are not an issue, if they are answered helpfully. As individual people are usually not asking the same questions over and over, this appears to be the case. As your experience on and perception of the site seems different from anyone else’s, you may want to reevaluate whether this site is a good place for you. The reaction seems to be the same wherever you interact with the SE sites.

@Stephie I didn't say the questions themselves were an issue. I said they indicate that "Everyone else reads the guidance and understands it" is patently false. They show that people don't understand the "rules" and that I am not the broken finger,

@Stephie I can at least understand textbook examples of conversational implicatures.

True, not everyone gets "the rules". Some new folks think SE sites are forums. Others think that, because it's a Q/A site, every question is appropriate and ought to be answered. These folks either learn/stay (as most now here have) or get frustrated/angry and leave. Then there are the infrequent users who, no matter how much guidance they get, keep asking and/or answering inappropriately. Some have recognizable issues (trolls, mental illnesses, e.g. OCD/ODD/other), some are a mystery. Sadly these folks end up getting banned. You're a mystery, but you're dancing on the edge. Please stop.

@anongoodnurse Some people ask to be told what the rules are or ask to get a passage explained/interpreted and they get no answer. But we digress we aren't discussing the question any more.

How many upvotes have you gotten for your "unanswered" questions? How many down votes? How many up/down votes did the responses get (including comments)? What does that tell you (not literally,unless you do hear voices) about your "questions"?

This isn't a matter of taste. It's a matter of written guidelines that you cannot or will not accept, and the outcome will be the same either way. ignorantia juris non excusat.

@anongoodnurse Impossibilium nulla obligatio est. I have been repeatedly told to look for the underlying intent. Blamed for being a rules lawyer.

@GeorgeNtoulos with regards to Impossibilium nulla obligatio est: there is something much simpler than the rules and customs of Stack Exchange that you have been told repeatedly here and on other sites of the network. And you have been told both in clear words and via downvotes of questions and upvotes of comments: Stop the endless discussion in comments. Stop asking the same questions over and over and on different Meta sites. If that’s impossible for you, it will be made possible from other sides.

@Stephie what I want to understand are the rules and "customs" of Stack Exhange.

Your first line is incorrect. There is no rule for General Questions - General Answers. In fact, for most sites the opposite is true, where we want very specific answers to very specific questions. Generally to try and get detailed answers to problems encountered.
This is slightly more challenging on the handful of more subjective sites, such as Travel, Music, Parenting etc., where we are less likely to be able to define a specific problem to solve.
